# Inexplicable random "000000" Guid values in fake method - FakeItEasy in .Net 6

Tags: .net-6.0, fakeiteasy, ef-core-6.0

So I have this fake object definition, that has a fake method in it :

```
// Note: This is a simplified version of my code. 
// If it turns out that such issues could come from complex method prototypes, 
// then I'll post the full setup.

IFooRepositoryClass fooRepo = A.Fake<IFooRepositoryClass>();

A.CallTo(() => fooRepo.FooFunctionAsync(A<Guid>.Ignored).ReturnsLazily(
    (Guid fooId) => {
        fooInternalObject.DoSomething(fooId);
    }
);
```

As you can see, nothing out of the ordinary.

Later, in my XUnit tests, I call the fake function :

```
Guid testGuid = new Guid("aaaaaaaa-9a88-4746-914b-aaaaaaaaaaaa"); //I changed to "aaaaa" to make it easily recognizable
await fooRepo.FooFunctionAsync(testGuid).configureAwait(false);
```

I put a breakpoint on that instruction :
`await fooRepo.FooFunctionAsync(testGuid).configureAwait(false);` 
...I see that testGuid is indeed *aaaaaaaa-9a88-4746-914b-aaaaaaaaaaaa*

But then I put a breakpoint inside, on this instruction :
`fooInternalObject.DoSomething(fooId);`

To my great surprise, ***fooId* has a weird value with lots of zeros, different at each run!**

*f933b838-007b-0000-0000-000000000000*

*785bb288-001a-0000-0000-000000000000*

*4d4bb8d8-0012-0000-0000-000000000000*
etc.
As you can see it's not Guid.Empty, just Guids that look suspiciously manufactured.

What the hell is going on? Can FakeItEasy do that to Guids?

**Even weirder :**  I shared my branch to a colleague, and he checked it out. So he has the *exact same code as me.*
...But **for him, fooId has the expected value, i.e. the value of *testGuid*!** We peeked at each other's screen and every execution conditions seem identical. Only the Guid differs at the breakpoint : Expected value for him, bogus values for me. I cleaned the solution, rebuilt, even restarted VS. to no avail!

What the hell is going on? x2

I'm not expecting anyone to fix my unit tests, but maybe this is a well-known behaviour under certain conditions. **Ever seen that? Especially those weird 000000 Guid values?** Something has to differ between our setups, but I need a lead to know where to look.

Comment: This has all the hallmarks of a threading problem.

Comment: Perhaps you could try running the application from command line as to exclude any involvement with Visual Stuadio itself...very strange behaviour though.

Comment: @MatthewWatson please be more explicit?

Comment: Note: @jeancallisti crossposted to [FakeItEasy issue 1882](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/1882)

Comment: For any future reader: I still haven't found the explanation to this.

Comment: I wonder if it could have been Linqpad (running on my system by mistake) intercepting the values, a bit like Postman would intercept some HTTP queries/data.